# Gitosis installation error: setup.py RuntimeError

Tags: git, git-bash, gitosis

I'm trying to install gitosis on Window 10.
I have Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) and have EasyInstall package installed. I also have my Git environment ready.

I tried the following code on my git bash to clone the gitosis from the URL.

```
$git clone https://github.com/tv42/gitosis.git
```

This ran just fine.

```
Cloning into 'gitosis'...
remote: Counting objects: 661, done.
remote: Total 661 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 661
Receiving objects: 100% (661/661), 118.12 KiB | 374.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (430/430), done.
```

However, when I try to run setup.py as follows,

```
$cd gitosis
$python setup.py install
```

I get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 54, in <module>
    'gitosis.templates': subdir_contents('gitosis/templates'),
  File "setup.py", line 17, in subdir_contents
    return list(_subdir_contents(path))
  File "setup.py", line 14, in _subdir_contents
    raise RuntimeError()
RuntimeError
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitosis is quite outdated, it is no longer maintained. Use [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) instead.